# Android monkey test choose a specific activity

Tags: android, android-activity, monkey-testing

I'm using the [Android monkey test](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) to test my android apps, it's works for my app, and is very cool. but I'd like to test an application activity in specific, how could i do that?

today I'm testing all app with:

```
$ adb shell monkey -p my.package -c android.intent.category.HOME -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -v 500 -s "a random number"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659036/using-monkey-in-a-subactivity-only-android-debugging

Comment: @StinePike that solutions need "Put your subactivities under one subpackage" but i don't want do it because because it would be too much work organizing the code to test each of my activities. I'm looking for something simple, like monkeytest is simple. :D

Comment: then I think it is better to write your own activity test cases

Comment: @StinePike I found a better way "i think be better", http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html, with this I can do python scripts to simulate events, so i can open a specific activity and with help of random number simulate monkey tests... i go try.

Comment: @StinePike works with monkey runner :), i answer my question with the script i using

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [Android monkey test](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkey.html) i cannot test a specific activity, but with [Android monkey runner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) i can do python scripts to simulate a monkey test, so i did a python script open the my activity and init the monkey test :)

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
from random import randint

print "get device"
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
package = 'my.packaget'
activity = 'my.package.activity'
runComponent = package + '/' + activity
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

#use commands like device.touch and device.drag to simulate a navigation and open my activity

#with your activity opened start your monkey test
print "start monkey test"
for i in range(1, 1000):
    #here i go emulate only simple touchs, but i can emulate swiper keyevents and more... :D
    device.touch(randint(0, 1000), randint(0, 800), 'DOWN_AND_UP')

print "end monkey test"
```

save teste.py and run

```
$ monkeyrunner teste.py
```

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me. Add `category` in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="MonkeyActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Where `MonkeyActivity` will perform an initialization setup for testing and from shell:

```
adb shell monkey -p my.package -c android.intent.category.MONKEY -v 500
```

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> -c     If you specify one or more categories this way, the Monkey will only allow the system to visit activities that are listed
>   with one of the specified categories. If you don't specify any
>   categories, the Monkey will select activities listed with the category
>   Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER or Intent.CATEGORY_MONKEY. To specify
>   multiple categories, use the -c option multiple times — one -c option
>   per category.

so you remove the DEFAULT and LAUNCHER category from your command, add the MONKEY one to the activity you want to test in your manifest and the command is now simply:

```
$ adb shell monkey -p my.package -c -v 500 -s "a random number"
```

Comment: if i no send the -c ... i get the follow error: "** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.".

Comment: did you add the MONKEY category to the activity in the androidmanifest.xml? You need something like  
<intent-filter><category android:name="android.intent.category.MONEY" /> </intent-filter>

in your activity definition

Comment: I try it, i did a activity with "android.intent.action.CATEGORY_MONKEY" and "android.intent.action.MONKEY" and run "$ adb shell monkey -p my.package -v 500 -s 4" and complet outpout is: ":Monkey: seed=0 count=500
:AllowPackage: my.package
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted."

Comment: You're nearly there, you just need to set a category as monkey instead of an action

Comment: no :(, i set "<intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MONKEY" />
            </intent-filter>" and try "$ adb shell monkey -p my.package -v 500 -s 4" and returns ":Monkey: seed=0 count=500
:AllowPackage: my.package
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted."

Comment: and try run with "$ adb shell monkey -p br.com.zazcar.tablet -c android.intent.category.MONKEY -v 500 -s 4" and returns ":Monkey: seed=0 count=500
:AllowPackage: my.package
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted."

Comment: How did you end up doing it ademar111190 ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me just worked with:

```
-c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

according to my manifest standard category entry:

```
<activity
                android:name="pl.com.infinitysoftware.carassistant.app.CarAssistantMainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:launchMode="singleTask"
                android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
</activity>
```