# Start Activity for testing

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I 've got a Quiz app using Realm db. Every time the user selects an answer she clicks a button and new text for Question appears. 
Thats it until she reaches the end where I start a new Activity and display a score based on correct answers.

How should I start/test ( with Espresso I guess ) that activity without having to enter manually every time *all* the answers and click the button after each answer until I reach the last one?

What I need is to pass some mock data to a variable and make an Intent but I dont know how and cant find anything related with this in Espresso

Comment: What if you make that activity as the launcher activity, so that that activity is the first activity your app shows?

Comment: hmm I guess its possible something like that but I'm not sure if this is a "good" practice and if im allowed to alter my src files structure just for testing.

Comment: It is your app. You are testing it. You can alter the src files for the mere purpose of testing and then revert back.

Comment: It's like saying I won't check if my website is hack-proof or not because Hacking is bad.

Comment: hehe :) ok you are right. What I  think will be a problem is that I have to do this every time I change my code - I was thinking that maybe with some framework I wouldnt have to change something from my code.

Answer (score 63):

You can launch your next activity with a custom intent like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class NextActivityTest {

  @Rule
  public ActivityTestRule<NextActivity> activityRule 
     = new ActivityTestRule<>(
        NextActivity.class,
        true,     // initialTouchMode
        false);   // launchActivity. False to customize the intent

  @Test
  public void intent() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("your_key", "your_value");

    activityRule.launchActivity(intent);

    // Continue with your test
  }
}
```

Full example: https://github.com/chiuki/android-test-demo

Blog post: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/espresso-21-activitytestrule.html

Comment: Can I use this together with UiAutomator in order to test my notifications?

Comment: @chiuki I'm trying same code and it shows green, but when I'm adding `intended(hasComponent(NextActivity.class.getName()));` 
I got `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(org.hamcrest.Matcher, android.support.test.espresso.intent.VerificationMode, java.util.List)' on a null object reference`

Comment: As `ActivityTestRule` is deprecated, this Kotlin example may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67929217/3692788

Answer (score 11):

For Devs using AndroidX for testing, things are a bit changed.

This is an example UI Test case for testing whether my intended activity opens after clicking on the textview.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle
import androidx.test.core.app.ActivityScenario
import androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView
import androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions
import androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents
import androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended
import androidx.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasComponent
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId
import com.softway.dhananjay.tournamentapp.tournament.TournamentActivity
import org.junit.Test

class MainActivityTest {

    @Test
    fun tournament_activity_starts_onClick_of_textView() {

        Intents.init()

        val activityScenario: ActivityScenario<MainActivity> =
            ActivityScenario.launch(MainActivity::class.java)


        activityScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)

        onView(withId(R.id.startTextView)).perform(ViewActions.click())

        intended(hasComponent(TournamentActivity::class.java.name))

        Intents.release()

        activityScenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void launchApp(){
        // Launch the app
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();
        final Intent intent = context.getPackageManager()
                .getLaunchIntentForPackage(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE);
        // Clear out any previous instances
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);

        // Wait for the app to appear
        device.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE).depth(0)),
                LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
    }
```

Comment: what is `device` object?

Answer (score 1):

First, see this question : [Android Monkey Runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019290/android-monkey-test-choose-a-specific-activity)

Then you can see these guides :[Monkey Runner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)

It makesyou usePython to test your android activity outside of your source. So, you can trigger things and get to specific activitiesl like this :

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
from random import randint

print "get device"
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
package = 'my.packaget'
activity = 'my.package.activity'
runComponent = package + '/' + activity
device.startActivity(component=runComponent)

#use commands like device.touch and device.drag to simulate a navigation and open my activity

#with your activity opened start your monkey test
print "start monkey test"
for i in range(1, 1000):
    #here i go emulate only simple touchs, but i can emulate swiper keyevents and more... :D
    device.touch(randint(0, 1000), randint(0, 800), 'DOWN_AND_UP')

print "end monkey test"
```

save it and then run : `monkeyrunner test.py`

Comment: thanks for the links. I'll definitely check them and report back.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the intent to launch dialer activity using below code.

```
    @Rule    
public IntentsTestRule<DialerActivity> mActivityRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(
            DialerActivity.class);

    private static final String PHONE_NUMBER = "1234567890";
    private static final Uri INTENT_DATA_PHONE_NUMBER = Uri.parse("tel:" + PHONE_NUMBER);
    private static String PACKAGE_ANDROID_DIALER = "com.android.phone";

    static {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            // Starting with Android Lollipop the dialer package has changed. 

            PACKAGE_ANDROID_DIALER = "com.android.server.telecom";
        }
    }

    @Test    public void testDialerIntent()throws Exception
    {
        intending(not(isInternal())).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null));
        onView(withId(R.id.edit_text_caller_number)).perform(typeText(PHONE_NUMBER));
        onView(withId(R.id.button_call_number)).perform(click());
        intended(allOf(
                hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL),
                hasData(INTENT_DATA_PHONE_NUMBER),
                toPackage(PACKAGE_ANDROID_DIALER)));
    }


}
```

For more detailed description refer my blog post -
http://qaautomated.blogspot.in/2016/02/how-to-test-dialer-activity-with.html

Comment: copy paste, without any explanation what is being done or in context wth the question.