# How to instrument an acitivity which takes the command line parameter?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-espresso, android-testing

I am trying instrument an activity which will take the parameters from command line.

**Launching App using Command line**

```
adb shell am start -e "parameter" "test"  -n com.test.example/.MainActivity
```

**App Source code:**

```
public class MainActivity{
     @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("paramerter") == "test") {
        //..other code
    }
}
```

**Instrumentation code:**

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public final ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> rule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class, true, false);

    @Test
    public void testLaunchActivity() throws Exception {
           mActivityRule.getActivity();
    }
}
```

**How to pass the parameters to getActivity() ?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Start Activity for testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191715/start-activity-for-testing)